# Unsure how they get the $\pi/4$ and $8x$ in this problem

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

How do they get to the step with the $\pi/4$ and $8x$ in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\pi\int_0^5x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx=\frac{\color{red}8}{\color{green}8}\left(2\pi\int_0^5x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx\right)=$$

$$=\frac{2\pi}{\color{green}8}\int_0^5\color{red}8x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx=\frac\pi4\int_0^58x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx$$